# Prediction model problem

Tags: time-series, forecasting, sas

I am trying to design a model that can estimate the number of customers I will receive in every store every month using the number of customers I received every month in every store for the last five years up to and including the day before's numbers. How can I even approach this from a programming perspective? What kind of a mathematical representation would be best in this case? I want the model to always pull the last five years' information, including the day prior.

I estimated (forecasted) how many customers I will receive every month for each store; however, for some reason, the number is not always right. I want to be able to pull information as recent as the last five years but including the first ten days of the month in order to predict the remainder of the month's traffic. Essentially, I need the most recent information included in my prediction, meaning using all information including "yesterday's".

I am thinking of using the Poisson GLM or Poisson time series but I am trying to avoid the time series regression.

Any suggestions or ideas on where to search for an answer or on how to solve this? I am using SAS.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are trying to avoid time series methods?

Comment: I am avoiding it because the days of one month this year will not match the same day of the same month the following year. (for example Jan 2 this year may fall on a Monday when last year that same day was on a Tuesday).

Comment: Also, if there is no other way, how would I do it using time series method?

Comment: This is an interesting problem. It seems that any model you use to predict the total number of customers each month should rely on two numbers: the number of customers you've already seen this month and some prediction for the number of customers yet to be seen this month.

Comment: The answer to this will certainly involve using the standard time-series tools of adjusting for seasonality and making forecasts.

Comment: @PeterEills Can you explain more please?

Comment: What is your existing model that is not always right?  Can this model be improved by adding some outside economic metrics - CPI or S&P500 for example? You don't mention your domain or geography - but since you have dates, you could even add historical weather - during hot weather people buy more A/C units for example.